# Части аргументов функции , оператор rest

Tags: javascript

Как мне изменить  параметры и тело функции addOverNum() так, чтобы она считала сумму только тех аргументов, которые больше чем заданное число. Это число должно быть первым параметром функции.

```js
function addOverNum(one, ...args) {
  let total = 0;

  for (const arg of args) {
    total += arg;
  }
  return total;
}
console.log(addOverNum(50, 15, 27))
console.log(addOverNum(10, 12, 4, 11, 48, 10, 8))
```

Comment: Ты ведь знаешь про `if` ?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский спасибо, походу я идиот(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А что мешает проверять условие при помощи хотя бы `if`?

```js
function addOverNum(one, ...args) {
  let total = 0;

  for (const arg of args) {
    if (arg > one) {
        total += arg;
    }
  }
  return total;
}
console.log(addOverNum(50, 15, 27))
console.log(addOverNum(10, 12, 4, 11, 48, 10, 8))
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно даже в одну строчку :)

```js
const addOverNum = (one, ...args) => args.reduce((sum, el) => el > one ? sum + el : sum, 0);

console.log(addOverNum(50, 15, 27));
console.log(addOverNum(10, 12, 4, 11, 48, 10, 8));
```

[Вариант от Grundy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1426083/%d0%a7%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80-rest#comment2541205_1426102) с преобразованием `true` в `1`, а `false` в `0`:

```js
const addOverNum = (one, ...args) => args.reduce((sum, el) => sum + (el > one) * el, 0);

console.log(addOverNum(50, 15, 27));
console.log(addOverNum(10, 12, 4, 11, 48, 10, 8));
```

Comment: Это слишкомБ для меня пока что)

Comment: `+=` не нужен, в принципе тернарный оператор тоже: `args.reduce((sum, el) => sum + (el > one)*el, 0)`

Comment: @Grundy Ну тернарный оператор более понятен, чем преобразование булевых в числа :) А на счёт `+=` согласен, привык писать что сумма равна увеличенному значению

Comment: @Grundy Добавил и твой вариант :)